# Catching latest column value change in SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

How can I get the date for the latest value change in one column with one SQL query?

Possible database situation:

```
Date        State

2012-11-25  state one
2012-11-26  state one
2012-11-27  state two
2012-11-28  state two
2012-11-29  state one
2012-11-30  state one
```

So result should return 2012-11-29 as latest change state. If I group by State value, I will get the date for first time I have that state in database.

The query will group the table on state and show the state and in the date field the latest date created of that state.

From the given input the output would be

```
Date               State

2012-11-30        state one
2012-11-28        state two
```

Comment: Your latest 'date' change is November 30th. But you want to see the latest insert/update to the table? Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: He wants (as far as I understand) to see the last date where state was differnt than the date before.

Comment: i need latest date when column State is changed,not latest inserted row. For 30th column State had same value as on 29th. Get it now?

Comment: +1 for the mind stimulating question :)

Answer (score 2):

This will get you the last state:

```
-- Query 1
SELECT state
FROM tableX 
ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 1 ;
```

Encapsulating the above, we can use it to get the date just before the last change:

```
-- Query 2
SELECT t.date
FROM tableX AS t
  JOIN
    ( SELECT state
      FROM tableX 
      ORDER BY date DESC
        LIMIT 1
    ) AS last
    ON last.state <> t.state
ORDER BY t.date DESC
    LIMIT 1 ;
```

And then use that to find the date (or the whole row) where the last change occurred:

```
-- Query 3
SELECT a.date                         -- can also be used:   a.*
FROM tableX AS a 
  JOIN
    ( SELECT t.date
      FROM tableX AS t
        JOIN
          ( SELECT state
            FROM tableX 
            ORDER BY date DESC
              LIMIT 1
          ) AS last
          ON last.state <> t.state
      ORDER BY t.date DESC
          LIMIT 1
    ) AS b
    ON a.date > b.date
ORDER BY a.date
  LIMIT 1 ;
```

Tested in **[SQL-Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e7b8d/11)**

---

And a solution that uses MySQL variables:

```
-- Query 4
SELECT date
FROM
  ( SELECT t.date
         , @r := (@s <> state) AS result 
         , @s := state AS prev_state
    FROM tableX AS t
      CROSS JOIN
        ( SELECT @r := 0, @s := '' 
        ) AS dummy 
    ORDER BY t.date ASC 
  ) AS tmp
WHERE result = 1
ORDER BY date DESC
  LIMIT 1 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the answer:

```
SELECT 
    DISTINCT State AS State, `Date`
FROM 
    Table_1 t1
WHERE t1.`Date`=(SELECT MAX(`Date`) FROM Table_1 WHERE State=t1.State)
```

...and the test:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8b0d8/5

Comment: Why making it so complex, when this can be done through a simple group by, check my answer

Comment: @SashiKant Your answer is working fine in case of two columns, but if the table has more than than two columns (and it turns out it does) my answer will be able to return all the values from the row with MAX date.

Comment: Morten is right, your example return 30th as date and it should return 29th for my need.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Don't use as if it was, this can confuse readers.

Answer (score 0):

If you add another column 'changed datetime' you can fill this using an update trigger that inserts NOW(). If you query your table ordering on the changed column, it will endup first.

```
CREATE TRIGGER `trigger` BEFORE UPDATE ON `table` 
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
SET ROW.changed = NOW();
END$$
```

Comment: problem is that i simplified table here. I have other columns beside this that can be changed too but they are not important here. Meaning other columns can be changed and state could stay the same. I need to get latest change only for State column. Also when does changed trigger? What if there in insert to that table with same State value? Is it possible to query and get result without altering table structure?

Comment: You can add an insert trigger too. It looks nearly the same as this trigger (look at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/trigger-syntax.html for more information)

Comment: And you can add an if statement around the set row.changed = now() that filters on the correct requirement of when to change.

Answer (score 0):

Try this ::

```
Select 
    MAX(`Date`), state from mytable 

    group by state
```

Comment: this query return 2012-11-30 in my example,and i need 2012-11-29 (first time that column state was changed to current state).

Comment: As the OP said. This was not the answer to his question.

Answer (score 0):

If you had been using postgres, you could compare different rows in the same table using "LEAD .. OVER" I have not managed to find the same functionallity in mysql.

A bit hairy, but I think this will do:

```
select min(t1.date) from table_1 t1 where 
  (select count(distinct state) from table_1 where table_1.date>=t1.date)=1
```

Basically, this asks for the first time no changes in state is found for any later values. Be warned, it may be this query scales terribly for large data sets....

Comment: Morrten your are right. Execute time here will be important, as this table in reality has almost 500k rows.

Comment: Thanks for a really interesting question :-) I really don't know how this query will use indexes, look carefully at how the query is planned (at least if you will run it on a production db where a query "pulling it down" will be a disaster...) It may also be it runs just fine...

Comment: First testing seems like this will run really slow. Execution is still not over :D Even though i created indexes on columns DatasetDate and State to be quicker.

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that you cannot (I think) put an index on an aggregate function. If that is possible, the query will run smooth, although it will use some time on building up the index the first time.

Answer (score 0):

I think your best choice here are analytical functions. Try this - it should be OK performance-wise:

```
SELECT *
FROM test
WHERE my_date = (SELECT MAX (my_date)
                FROM (SELECT MY_DATE
                        FROM (  SELECT MY_DATE,
                                       STATE,
                                       LAG (state) OVER (ORDER BY MY_DATE)
                                          lag_val
                                  FROM test
                              ORDER BY MY_DATE) a
                       WHERE state != lag_val))
```

In the inner select, the LAG function gets the previous value in the STATE column and in the outer select I mark the date of a change - those with lag value different than the current state value. And outside, I'm getting the latest date from those dates of a change... I hope that this is what you needed.

Comment: MySQL does not have the LAG() function.

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT MAX(DATE) FROM YOUR_TABLE
```

Above answer doesn't seem to satisfy what OP needs.

**UPDATED ANSWER WITH AFTER INSERT/UPDATE TRIGGER**

```
DELCARE @latestState varchar;
DELCARE @latestDate date;
CREATE TRIGGER latestInsertTrigger AFTER INSERT ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    IF OLD.DATE <> NEW.date THEN 
      SET @latestState = NEW.state 
      SET @latestDate = NEW.date
    END IF
END
;

CREATE TRIGGER latestUpdateTrigger AFTER UPDATE ON myTable
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN 
    IF OLD.DATE = NEW.date AND OLD.STATE <> NEW.STATE THEN 
      SET @latestState = NEW.state 
      SET @latestDate = NEW.date
    END IF
END
;
```

You may use the following query to get the latest record added/updated:

```
SELECT DATE, STATE FROM myTable
WHERE STATE = @latestState
OR DATE = @latestDate 
ORDER BY DATE DESC
;
```

Results:

```
DATE                                STATE
November, 30 2012 00:00:00+0000     state one
November, 28 2012 00:00:00+0000     state two
November, 27 2012 00:00:00+0000     state two
```

The above query results needs to be limitted to 2, 3 or n based on what you need.

Frankly it seems like you want to get max from both columns based on the data sample you have given. Assuming that your state only increases with the date. Only I wish if the `state` was an `integer` :D
Then union of two max sub queries on both columns would have solved it easily. Still a string manipulation regex can find what's the max in state column. Finally this approach needs `limit x`. However it still has **lope hole**. *Anyway it took me sometime to figure your need out* :$

Comment: No, that is not what the question was about.

Comment: I asked OP a question in the comments. Because I had in mind that he will need an insert update trigger however it's not clear what he wants.

Comment: I told my problem few times here, i need date when the State column was not the same as the day before (Morten got me right). I think your insert trigger will set date even if inserted state value is same as it was on previous insert.

Comment: @MortenSickel it just didn't click to me :$ I would like to get the logic right, as we all share and  learn, regardless of its being an answer. :)

Comment: @bonCodigo thx for trying. but unfortunately state is not only increasing in time. situation can go to any state any time. For example state st1, st2, st3, st1, st1, st3,st1 ...

Comment: I think your comment is based on my last explanation in the answer. If you look at the editted triggers, does it do what you need now (based on your sample date and expected output)?

Comment: How i can execute that? Using mysql workbench DECLARE variable_name return error, and if i use procedure for declaring cant create trigger inside procedure?

Comment: There are local variables and session variables. You can declare a session variable in this way `:SET @car := 'defaultvalue';` or a local variable in this way `:DECLARE @car varchar(30)`